# How do you load different Selenium2 settings depending on environment?

Tags: java, xml, testing, selenium, automated-tests

I'm on a huge project now which is introducing some Selenium into their test team, which up until now has been mostly manual. They have 3 different environments that the tests can be run in (development, test-development and test-production).

The Selenium code is written in Java, using WebDriver/HTMLUnit. I am looking for a way to switch Selenium settings such as which host name and port the browser should access, other browser-settings, test data, depending on which environment the tests are running in. Preferably automatically somehow, or a small change you could do depending on environment. Also, how should these settings be stored? XML?

Comment: How about running tests with Maven and using Maven's parameters or profiles?

Comment: Hmm.. Did you checkout selenium-grid?

Comment: Personally I like Gradle, but Maven will do the job for you as well

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I'll check out running the tests with Maven and using profiles.